# [UITextField retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, swift2, uitextfield

I get this message:

> [UITextField retain]: message sent to deallocated instance.

I understand the message BUT I do not know what "message" is sent and how to stop it from happening....

This code produces the error:

```
 func dismissController() {
       self.view.endEditing(true)
             self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
           }
```

While the following works "fine" I am not sure why I have to delay before dismissing the controller:

```
func dismissController() {
       self.view.endEditing(true)

        let delay = 0.75 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)


        }

           }
```

EDIT:(almost full code):

```
 @IBOutlet weak var locationTextView: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userIDTextView: UITextField!
   var treeLocationArray = NSMutableArray()
    var treeUserIDArray = NSMutableArray()
```

let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    var pickerButton = UIButton()
    var keyboardButton = UIButton()
    var locationIsSelected = true

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//....

 locationTextView.delegate = self
        userIDTextView.delegate = self
//Get the Plist... etc

 treeLocationArray = dict?.objectForKey("Location") as! NSMutableArray
        treeUserIDArray = dict?.objectForKey("UserID") as! NSMutableArray

 locationTextView.text = userPrefs.objectForKey("DefaultLocation") as? String
            userIDTextView.text = userPrefs.objectForKey("DefaultName") as? String
             locationTextView.text = userPrefs.objectForKey("DefaultLocation") as? String

  /// Create a view for the Accessory View
        let customView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 50))
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()


        /// Setup the picker button
        pickerButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(60 , 8, 32, 32) )
        pickerButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"dropIcon"), forState: .Normal)
        pickerButton.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        pickerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UserDefaultsViewController.pickerTapped), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        customView.addSubview(pickerButton)

        /// Setup the keyboard button
        keyboardButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(10 , 8, 32, 32) )
        keyboardButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"keyboardIcon"), forState: .Normal)
        keyboardButton.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        keyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UserDefaultsViewController.keyboardTapped), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        customView.addSubview(keyboardButton)

        locationTextView.inputAccessoryView = customView
        userIDTextView.inputAccessoryView = customView

}

 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

        if textField == locationTextView {
            locationIsSelected = true


        }

        if textField == userIDTextView {
            locationIsSelected = false

        }


        self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()

    }


    func keyboardTapped(){

        if locationIsSelected {

            locationTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            locationTextView.inputView = nil
            locationTextView.becomeFirstResponder()

        }

        else {

            userIDTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            userIDTextView.inputView = nil
            userIDTextView.becomeFirstResponder()

        }


    }

    func pickerTapped(){

        if locationIsSelected {

            locationTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            locationTextView.inputView = nil
            locationTextView.inputView = pickerView
            locationTextView.becomeFirstResponder()

        }

        else {

            userIDTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            userIDTextView.inputView = nil
            userIDTextView.inputView = pickerView
            userIDTextView.becomeFirstResponder()

        }

    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        var numberOfComponents = Int()

        if locationIsSelected {
            numberOfComponents = treeLocationArray.count
        }

        else {
            numberOfComponents = treeUserIDArray.count
        }

        return numberOfComponents
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        var numberOfComponents = Int()

        if locationIsSelected {
            numberOfComponents = treeLocationArray.count
        }

        else {
            numberOfComponents = treeUserIDArray.count
        }

        return numberOfComponents
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        var componetString = String()

        if locationIsSelected {
            componetString = (treeLocationArray[row] as? String)!
        }

        else {
            componetString = (treeUserIDArray[row] as? String)!
        }

        return componetString

    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if locationIsSelected {

            if treeLocationArray.count >= 1 {
            locationTextView.text = treeLocationArray[row] as? String

            }
        }

        else {

            if treeUserIDArray.count >= 1 {

            userIDTextView.text = treeUserIDArray[row] as? String

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: are you using delay somewhere else which later access that textfield variable ?

Comment: No. Nowhere else... I have only added the delay here because of the crash

Comment: can you maybe create a sample proj that reproduces this ? and upload on github to look at

Comment: Where is the textfield? Is there perhaps a strong reference to it where there should be a weak one? Eg, `@IBOutlet var someTextField: UITextField!` vs the correct `@IBOutlet weak var someTextField: UITextField!`

Comment: Please see edited Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens because you have call to dismissViewControllerAnimated. Due to VC life cycle all objects, that this VC holds will be deallocated. That means, that all manipulations with UI after dismiss are not memory-safe.

From the documentation:

> This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for
>   the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one,
>   it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If the force
>   parameter is set to true, the text field is never even asked; it is
>   forced to resign.

So, your VC had been deallocated while endEditing was looking thorough hierarchy, as I guess. It's the only one reason, that may cause memory problem.

Why do you need call to endEditing before dismissing? simply dismiss VC without this call. if you have logic, that depends on endEditing - separate it and call instead of endEditing. Hope this helps.

UPDATE:

Try to call endEditing in viewWillDisappear - this triggers view to resign first responder right before it will be dismissed.

Comment: I call endEditing because it will crash if I don't... If I call endEditing by adding it as gestureRecognizer on the view to resignFirstResponder then the app works fine. So I thought if I added it there it would not crash.But still I get the crash if I don't "delay" things (hope it makes sense)

Comment: @GeorgeAsda, could you please update question with error, if you don't call endEdining ? and one more - try to call endEditing somewhere in viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear

Comment: Oh man... you are my hero... Calling endEditing in viewWillDisappear did it!

Comment: @GeorgeAsda, ok, i will update answer, please confirm =)